# php print different color in rows

Tags: php

I try to print out all user email from table,
but i want odd number print in red
even number print in blue.
how to do this in while loop?

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);

$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$num=mysql_num_rows($SQL);
$start=0;

while($start<$num){
    $result_id=mysql_result($SQL, $start, "id");
    $result_email=mysql_result($SQL, $start, "email");

    echo "<b style='color:red'>" . $result_id . $result_email . "</b><br/>";
    echo "<b style='color:blue'>" . $result_id . $result_email . "</b><br/>";

    $start++;
    }
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I have to put this here, but could not resist - this is pretty much the [Fizz Buzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) question

Comment: *next time please use PDO instead mysql_query

Comment: You can do this with just css plus inline css is bad practice, as well as using `<b>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);

$SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$num=mysql_num_rows($SQL);
$start=0;

while($start<$num){
    $result_id=mysql_result($SQL, $start, "id");
    $result_email=mysql_result($SQL, $start, "email");
    if ($start&1) {
      echo "<b style='color:red'>" . $result_id . $result_email . "</b><br/>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<b style='color:blue'>" . $result_id . $result_email . "</b><br/>";
    }
    $start++;
    }
```

Comment: How `$start&1` works here? Whether it should take all odd ones?

Comment: @Justin no clue. It just does. Couldn't find any documentation anywhere

Comment: It's a [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) via [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889407/how-does-this-code-block-works)

Comment: Yeah but I can't find in the PHP.net documentation. I found this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php, but it doesn't seem to describe this behavior.