# How does this code block works?

Tags: php

I can't understand how the following code works.

```
$start = 1;
while($start<10){
    if ($start&1) {
      echo "ODD  ".$start." <br/> ";
    }
    else {
      echo "EVEN  ".$start." <br/> ";
    }
    $start++;
}
```

The `$start&1` will return ODD and EVEN seperately.

**Output**

```
ODD 1
EVEN 2
ODD 3
EVEN 4
ODD 5
EVEN 6
ODD 7
EVEN 8
ODD 9
```

If we give `$start&2` instead of `$start&1`, it returns with another order.

How `&1` `&2` etc... works here?

Comment: What does this mean `if ($start&1) {`?

Comment: @Eritrea that's exactly the OP's question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [bitwise and operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

```
  0001 --> 1
& 0001
  ----
  0001 --> 1

  0010 --> 2
& 0001
  ----
  0000 --> 0

  0011 --> 3
& 0001
  ----
  0001 --> 1
```

Depending on the endianness, it will be either the leftmost or rightmost bit that matters in this check.  The above is &ing with 1.  In your second example, &ing with 2, that would be

```
  0001 --> 1
& 0010
  ----
  0000 --> 0

  0010 --> 2
& 0010
  ----
  0010 --> 2

  0011 --> 3
& 0010
  ----
  0010 --> 2
```

And for further comparison, here is 1-3 &ing with 3

```
  0001 --> 1
& 0011
  ----
  0001 --> 1

  0010 --> 2
& 0011
  ----
  0010 --> 2

  0011 --> 3
& 0011
  ----
  0011 --> 3
```

To see what is going on, follow the columns of the two numbers down.  If they are both a 1 then the result has the bit set in that position to a 1.  If either are a 0 then the result is a 0 in that position.  So for 2 & 3..

```
  0010 --> 2
& 0011
  ----
  0010
  ||||
  |||+- 0 and 1, so 0
  ||+-- 1 and 1, so 1
  ++--- 0 and 0, so 0

  0010 == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is based on the `&` operator  (the `AND` [***bitwise***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator):
`$start&1` will return true if the rightmost bit is 1 => the number is odd

For example, the binary representation of `5` (odd) is:

```
101
```

and `1`:

```
001
```

So `101 & 001` will return `001` which is also `true` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise operator `&` deals with [bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numbers). On computers numbers are stored as binary data (1's and 0's, also called "bits"). Here is a table of the numbers that are used in the loop.

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
5 = 0101
6 = 0110
7 = 0111
8 = 1000
9 = 1001
```

Unlike decimal numbers, binary numbers are read right to left. When you look at the table you can see that even and odd binary numbers end in `0` and `1`, respectively. Binary numbers that end in `0` are even, and those that end in `1` are odd.

What the `&` bitwise operator does is basically chip off the last digit from the binary representation of the decimal, and then returns it.

If we take the number 5 (`0101`) then we can set it up in pseudocode:

```
if last bit in 0101 is 1 then
    number is odd
otherwise
    number is even
```

As for the PHP code the expression `($start & 1)` returns either `1` or `0`. In PHP [type juggling](http://php.net/juggling) turns `1` into `true`, and `0` into `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It loops 9 times, each time it bitwise ands with 1 (that is it ands with the second binary digit to see if it is a mutliple of 2) and prints accordingly

Answer (score 0):

& is the bitwise and operator. In the expression, it's looking for births the two values share in common.

Here's a tutorial of PHP bitwise operator usage: http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/bitwise-operators.php